# How to store the output of a Perl script as a JSON array

Tags: json, perl

My program logs in to a list of IPs, identifies the software running on it, and prints the output.

I want the output to be in the form of a JSON array.

Can a JSON encode function be used for this?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use QA::unit::testbedinfo;

my @machines_under_test = ( ... ); # list of ip's listed here

sub test_1_get_install_info_of_machines_under_test {

    my ( $self ) = @_;
    my %output;

    foreach my $ip ( @machines_under_test ) {

        my $output = $self->{'queryObj'}->get_install_info( $ip );

        push @{ $output{$output} }, $ip;

        INFO( ' software version  running on machine ' . $ip . ' : ' . $output );
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Apart from your dreadful formatting which I have fixed, your code doesn't do anything that your narrative says it does. To the general question of whether you can represent an array in JSON, the answer is **yes**. But it sounds very much like you don't understand that the JSON format is just a string of characters. Maybe you should ask a different question?

Comment: And `test_1_get_install_info_of_machines_under_test` is a horrible name for a subroutine, and it underlines for me that you don't know what's going on. Any identifier must be concise and meaningful. To do that requires that the ID has a *context*. I'm known by `Borodin` here, which contains all the information that you need. If you forever referred to me as `Borodin of 83 Royal Gardens, Yeovil, Somerset England, alias of John Smith age 12` then everyone would soon get weary.

Comment: The code you show really doesn't make sense: (1) the sub gets `$self` as if it were a method while this isn't a package (let alone a class).  You don't show how it's called either (2) The way you write to `%output` disagrees with the description -- you are making a _key_ be the output and `$ip` being added to its arrayref-value. Huh?  Presumably you'd want `$output{$ip} = $output`, but I'm merely guessing here.  //  Can you update  your code so that it is clear what you do/want/have?  // Can you clafiry how you want this info organized in your JSON?  Read up on JSON first if needed.

Comment: On the face of it, yes a Perl data structure can easily be cast into a JSON string.  But you should explain clearly what is going on and what exactly you want in JSON, with code that you have (and that agrees with the description).  Otherwise people have to guess and that is no way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like you're building a hash, `%output`, which has software version numbers for keys and (references to) arrays of IP addresses for values, correct?  To output that structure as JSON, just use the [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module and print the output of the `to_json` function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.010;

use JSON 'to_json';

my %output = (
  '1.0' => [ qw( 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8 ) ],
  '1.1' => [ qw( 192.168.0.3 192.168.37.42 192.168.0.123 ) ]
);

# Note that to_json takes a reference to the structure, not the raw hash
say to_json(\%output);
```

Which produces the output:

```
{"1.0":["1.2.3.4","5.6.7.8"],"1.1":["192.168.0.3","192.168.37.42","192.168.0.123"]}
```